# Numerical Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Does anyone know how to solve this integral $\int_0^{x} \frac{1}{\frac{2}{x }-\alpha  \lambda  x ^2 e^{-\lambda  x }} \, dx$? If it is possible to numerical integration is also okay. I want to know $x$ value that makes this integral equals to some number like 50.  I mean what is value of $x$ that satisfies $\int_0^{x} \frac{1}{\frac{2}{x }-\alpha  \lambda  x ^2 e^{-\lambda  x }} \, dx=50$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your integral is not known by *Mathematica* to have a closed form. What are the values of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You can check `Integrate`, `NIntegrate` and `Solve` or `NSolve` in the documentation.

Comment: `NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0, WhenEvent[y[x] == 50, sol = x; "StopIntegration"]}, {}, {x, 0, Infinity}]; {x -> sol}`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f, g]

f[a_, λ_, x_] = (2/x - a λ x^2 E^(-λ x))^-1;

g[a_?NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[f[a, λ, t], {t, 0, x}]

Module[
 {a = 1, λ = 2, xmin = 1, xmax = 20, gmin, gmax},
 gmin = g[a, λ, xmin];
 gmax = g[a, λ, xmax];
 Manipulate[
  pt = {x /. FindRoot[g[a, λ, x] == val, {x, val}], val};
  Plot[g[a, λ, x], {x, xmin, xmax},
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
     Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}],
  {{val, (gmin + gmax)/2}, gmin, gmax, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very and very much. I appreciate your response. Have nice day